# How does onload work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, onload

In the book Pro HTML5 Games there is the following piece of code:

```
    // Load all data and images for a specific level
load:function(number){
    // declare a new currentLevel object
    game.currentLevel = { number: number, hero: [] };
    game.score = 0;
    $('#score').html('Score: '+game.score);
    var level=levels.data[number];

    //load the background, foreground, and slingshot images
    game.currentLevel.backgroundImage=loader.loadImage("images/backgrounds/"+level.background+
    ".png");
    game.currentLevel.foregroundImage=loader.loadImage("images/backgrounds/"+level.foreground+
    ".png");
    game.slingshotImage=loader.loadImage("images/slingshot.png");
    game.slingshotFrontImage =loader.loadImage("images/slingshot-front.png");

    //Call game.start() once the assets have loaded
    if(loader.loaded){
        game.start()
    } else {
        loader.onload = game.start;
    }
}
```

The loader object is the following:

```
var loader= {
loaded:true,
loadedCount:0, // Assets that have been loaded so far
totalCount:0, // Total number of assets that need to be loaded

init:function(){
    // check for sound support
    var mp3Support,oggSupport;
    var audio =document.createElement('audio');
    if (audio.canPlayType) {
        // Currently canPlayType() returns: "", "maybe" or "probably"
        mp3Support ="" != audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg');
        oggSupport ="" != audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"');
    } else {
        //The audio tag is not supported
        mp3Support =false;
        oggSupport =false;
    }
    // Check for ogg, then mp3, and finally set soundFileExtn to undefined
    loader.soundFileExtn =oggSupport?".ogg":mp3Support?".mp3":undefined;
},

loadImage:function(url){
    this.totalCount++;
    this.loaded =false;
    $('#loadingscreen').show();
    var image =new Image();
    image.src =url;
    image.onload =loader.itemLoaded;
    return image;
},

soundFileExtn:".ogg",

loadSound:function(url){
    this.totalCount++;
    this.loaded =false;
    $('#loadingscreen').show();
    var audio =new Audio();
    audio.src =url +loader.soundFileExtn;
    audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", loader.itemLoaded, false);
    return audio;
},

itemLoaded:function(){
    loader.loadedCount++;
    $('#loadingmessage').html('Loaded '+loader.loadedCount+' of '+loader.totalCount);
    if (loader.loadedCount === loader.totalCount){
        // Loader has loaded completely..
        loader.loaded=true;
        // Hide the loading screen
        $('#loadingscreen').hide();
        //and call the loader.onload method if it exists
        if(loader.onload){
            loader.onload();
            loader.onload =undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following questions:

1)If onload is a method, shouldn't we use it as, for example, `imageThatWeWantToLoad.onload(stuff we want to do after image has been loaded)`, instead of `imageThatWeWantToLoad.onload = (do what we want to do after image has been loaded)`?

2)What does `loader.onload=game.start;` part does (game is an object and start is a method defined inside the game object) exactly?
I think I understood that `loader.onload=game.start;` means that once the loader object has been loaded, `game.start` will be called, but since `game.start` is a method, shouldn't it be `loader.onload=game.start();` ?

3)Also, `onload` means 'data received by the browser' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `image.onload` is not intrinsically a method. It is just a property, just like `name` is a property in `dog` after we execute

```
dog = { name: null };
```

A property of an object is a method if it contains a function. So,

```
dog['bark'] = function() { console.log("Woof"); };
```

Now we could do `dog.bark()` to invoke this method.

If `image.onload` is a method (i.e. if it contains a function) at the time the image is loaded, it will be run by the browser. It is not a method that is meant for us to call, it is for us to *define*.

2) It does exactly what it looks like - assigns contents of `game.start` (a function) to `loader.onload`. Now both properties refer to the same function. If we did `loader.onload = game.start()`, it would execute `game.start` and assign the *result* of the execution to `loader.onload`; but we want to assign the function itself, so no parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

The property `loader.onload` is a pointer to a function (technically it's just a plain pointer but let's ignore that for a moment).

Doing:

```
loader.onload = game.start;
```

Assigns the function `game.start` to the pointer `loader.onload`.

Then later on, in the loader code you see:

```
if(loader.onload){
    loader.onload();
    loader.onload =undefined;
}
```

It basically checks if `loader.unload` has been assigned anything (`undefined` is considered false in javascript). If it has call the function it points to then set the pointer back to `undefined`.

The explanation above glosses over several facts about javascript. But it's basically what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Loader is object and `loadImage` is property defined on it.
2. The property `loader.onload` is a pointer to a function (anonymous)
3. `loader.onload = game.start;` // makes loader.onload point to game.start. i.e saying `game.start() === loader.onload();`

Answer (score 0):

Onload in JavaScript can be described as:

1. onload here is accessed as property and we are assigning the property with the result of the function. So function will execute and the final result will be assigned to the property. So basically calling of function and assigning the result to the property has done simultaneously in single line of code.
2. In this case, we want to know that whether loader onload method has executed or not by checking loader.loaded property. If it has executed then call game.start() without assigning to any function to execute in sequence as onload method has executed. If it has not executed then we have assigned the game.start function to loaded.onload function so we have used them as property to assign the function to another function, so now when onload method will be called, it will now execute game.start() function as onload is replaced by game.start.
3. Onload means that object has been loaded. We use onload event in body tag of html to know that webpage has loaded all the content and we may perform our actions now for smooth functioning.